# Unable to pass line to Scanner

Tags: java

```
Scanner kb=new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("\nDo you want to continue");
char answer=kb.next().charAt(0);
if(Character.toUpperCase(answer)=='Y') {
        System.out.println("\nType any message to get Value");
        String input=kb.nextLine();
        class2 obj=new class2(input);
        System.out.println("\n"+obj.getValue());
}
```

My program is not passing input to `class2`, it's just executing my method with empty input. I just tried every method, but none are working.

Comment: try to change to `kb.nextLine().charAt(0);`

Comment: Can you tell me why I have to use this nextLine instead of next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be solved by changing

```
char answer = kb.next().charAt(0);
```

to

```
char answer = kb.nextLine().charAt(0);
```

This is the solution because the next() method in Java does not advance the Scanner to the next line while nextLine() does.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1) make `char answer=kb.nextLine().charAt(0);`

2) make `String input=kb.next();`

**Option 1:** If you make it `nextLine()` it will consume the whole line and moves the cursor to next line. Thus there is no remaining string to be consumed.

**Option 2:** `next()` only consumes line till it finds a `space` and also it does not advances cursor to the next line. Thus for the first input if you type `"yopo"` the `nextLine()` will consume the remaining `blank` and you will not get anything.

In your case you should prefer the ***1st*** option.